# UIApplicationInvalidInterface Orientation

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have created an ios app. Now an error occured with following error messages.

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   "UIApplicationInvalidInterface Orientation" reason: 'preferrred
>   Interface orientaionForPresentation must be return a supported
>   interface orientation'

Any help will appreciated.

Comment: add your orientation methods you have used in your ViewController.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: its seems like your `supportedInterfaceOrientations` method doesn't contain Orientation you are returning from your `preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation`.

Comment: My app use navigationcontroller and tabbarcontroller with storyboard

Comment: try after adding key "Supported interface orientations" in plist.

Comment: @Ronak Chaniyara Any sample code or steps.

Comment: Make sure you have ticked atleast one of the device orientations in Project settings General tab

Comment: project setting device orientation check to portrait and landscape left and right. any other solution